# OAuth2 Configuration Issues: AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application:

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-api-management

Trying to get Oauth2.0 to work with APIM in my Azure space.

I have imported and setup an 2.0 Open API as the backend.  I am using the APIM developer portal as the client to call this backend API.  I have the dev portal App ID as the Client ID and using its Client Secret.  I tried using the provided redirect_uri for authorization code as the reply url and also tried using app.com/auth with same issue

When I  make a call to the API from the Developer Console, I prompted to sign in. I then sign in and get the following error:

AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application: 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Could you please your request sample?

Comment: Was able to resolve it.  I was pointing the reply url to the backend instead of the client

Answer (score 1):

Do follow this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad) to protect your API by using OAuth 2.0 with Azure Active Directory.

**Note:** This document applies to **App registrations(Legacy)**. If you used App registrations, there will be something different from the document.

[image]

It seems that the reply url configured for your **client app** is not correct.

Click OAuth2.0->click your oauth2 service->you will find the redirect_uri.

[image]

Go you your **client app** and replace the reply url with this redirect_uri.

[image]